# PHP array element access

Tags: php

Why does this work:

```
$parts = explode('#', $url);
$url = $parts[0];
```

while this doesn't:

```
$url = explode('#', $url)[0];
```

?

Comment: I know this feature was added in later versions of PHP. Before that version the former was the only way to access an array returned from a function.

Comment: The 2nd syntax wasn't added until PHP 5.4.  http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Comment: I think it was added in PHP 5.3

Comment: It does work from PHP 5.4 http://3v4l.org/uQXaN

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Direct de-referencing of an array, like in your second code example, was added to PHP 5.4. Before 5.4, it was a syntax error.

```
<= 5.3

    $foo = array(....);
    echo $foo[1];

>= 5.4

    echo array(...)[1];
```

Comment: was going to post the same; please add: http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php